# Which database should I use for a medium SaaS CRM?

Tags: database, nosql, cloud, saas

Which database should I use for a medium SaaS CRM? nosql or relational database?

- Oracle
- Sql Server
- CouchDB
- etc.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Wow, not giving us much to go on there. There are many good DBMS systems out there from the relational to document based to object based. One of the reasons there are so many is they each have advantages and disadvantages in different application scenarios. With so little to go on I'd say use the one you're familiar with unless there's a driving reason to use another.

Answer (score 0):

MYSQL would be a great idea as it is open source and is gaining acceptance in enterprise also.